# Recover local messages after renaming "Outlook 15" folder on a MAC

Tags: macos, outlook-mac

I was having an issue configuring an email account on Outlook for MAc. In order to test something I renamed the "Outlook 15" folder containing the profile and recreated it again by strarting outlook. This did not fix the problem and in order to roll back, I stoped outlook again and renamed the old "Outlook 15" folder back to its original name.

Then I started outlook and I got back my profile and email account, but some things did not recover as expected.

1. The look and feel of outlook for mack changed and it was not the same and before.
2. Second and most important, I had some localy saved emails that I can not access now.

By searching the file system I seem to find files with titles corresponding to the emails I can't access now, but I don't know how to open them again in Outlook.

Does anyone have a clue on what happened to those emails and how to access them again?

Thanks